# How to disable dgs-graphql framework controllers in swagger

Tags: graphql, swagger, netflix-dgs

I am using dgs-graphql and for REST Apis, I have configured the swagger (springdoc-open-api). When I am accessing the swagger ui, I am getting **dgs-rest-schema-json-controller** and **dgs-rest-controller** swaggers which are related to graphql.

How can I configure my swagger, so that those graphql swaggers wont appear in my swagger-ui?

Answer (score 0):

You can exclude certain packages via config https://springdoc.org/properties.html:

> springdoc.packages-to-exclude
>
> List of Strings.The list of packages to exclude (comma separated)

In application.yml

```
springdoc:
  packages-to-exclude: com.netflix.graphql.dgs.mvc
```